# What are PHP-FPM pools and what is pm.max_children?

Tags: nginx, drupal-7, php

I have a Drupal site with NGINX and PHP-FPM with 3 pools.

What I want to know is what are FPM pools or just give me links to good documentation, i've searched about this topic but all I found is how to configure "X" to obtain a better performance.

Also, what is pm.max_children? I recently notice in the log that when pool www1 reaches this value the pool www1 stops working, locking also a page on my site until I reload PHP-FPM. Why I'm reaching pm.max_children after some time? Is there a way to detect and react in this event... reloading PHP-FPM? Is there a way to avoid reaching pm.max_children?

Thanks all for your knowledge.

PD: I'm using perusio's configuration for Drupal and Nginx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can simply say that each pool is like a separate php, like for me i use pools to run each by a different user, give each the appropriate limits in terms of resources and such for separate websites running on the same server.

I don't understand though why 3 pools for same site, do you use an `upstream` in nginx?

As for `max_children` is the amount of spawned processes the fpm is allowed to spawn to handle concurrent connections, If you are having a lot of concurrent connections then you better increase that number, if the number is reached fpm won't spawn another child and wait for one to free to handle the waiting request.

**EDIT**:

Try playing with this config, might be useful, here's a snippet from the config file, by default it's commented.

```
; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For 
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
;pm.max_requests = 500
```

Here's also another one

```
; The timeout for serving a single request after which the worker process will
; be killed. This option should be used when the 'max_execution_time' ini option
; does not stop script execution for some reason. A value of '0' means 'off'.
; Available units: s(econds)(default), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Value: 0
;request_terminate_timeout = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I don't think I have that number of concurrent connections. It seems to me that some "processes" get locked and the count as an active concurrent connection. Does that make sense to you? I'm not sure if I'm using an upstream, I'm a using someone else configuration (https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx).

Comment: The only thing about having 3 pools I know is that if pool www1 reach pm.maxchildren then www2 will continue... which is good I think. At least that's what i understood in the pool status pages.

Comment: yea here's the config I was expecting https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx/blob/D7/upstream_phpcgi_unix.conf, anyway, I think the issue isn't from nginx it self, might be a page that doesn't timeout and keeps the connection occupied. I'm not sure though how we could detect something like that (which page)

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I think it's not a specific page, it's random. I tested this behavior at 5:00 AM Ecuador, Google Analitics Real Time shows nobody except me on the site. So, I navigate through many pages on the site until pm.max_children was reached, then it stopped and appended the error to the log. The last page I tested never load again, other pages on the site were good. After spotting the error I reload php-fpm, and the "locked" page loaded fine. Until now what I know is that a random page will be "locked" when pm.max_children is reached. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And if you don't reload does it stay stuck forever? or does it like get better after time ?

Comment: If I reload PHP-FPM then the locked page unlocks instantly. After some time another page will get locked randomly the same way. By now I'm executing a cron every 10 minutes to reload PHP-FPM. Also the status page of the pool is unreachable while a page is locked. I'm planing lo read the pool's status page to reload the pool only as needed, despite that reloading every 10 minutes does not seem to be a big impact on performance.

Comment: Check the part I added to the answer, might be a better alternative to the crontab method.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad but in my case max_requests was not a solution, I set this option before. I think request_slowlog_timeout will show me valuable information. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: how low did you set the `max_requests`? maybe you need it lower, or try setting fpm to ondemand so that it only spawns children when needed, might be slower but might be more stable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40941/discussion-between-beto-aveiga-and-mohammad-abushady)