# Laravel queue worker and pm.max_children

Tags: php, laravel

After increasing number of queue workers via Supervisor and `php artisan queue:work`, sometimes I get:

```
WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it
```

Does anyone know if `php artisan queue:work` caused the warning above?

Comment: What's "max_children" is wonderfully described in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19890183/6849366

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of `max_children` from here:

```
/etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Please note the PHP version and OS and change the path to match yours.

But when you say **sometimes**, it sounds you have slow PHP scripts.